# Suggesstions needed with Jquery in blogger

Tags: jquery, blogger

What I am trying to do in my blogger blog is remove the label that contains the seeds snippet before the tag.

Such as  In: Moskow, seeds_ILO

The html:

```html
<div class='postmeta'>
 <div class='seeds_remove'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
  <span class='label_remove'><data:label.name/></span>
</b:loop>

   <span class='publ'><b>Published on</b>  <data:post.timestamp/></span>
   <span class='pubb'><b>By:</b> <data:post.author/> </span>
   <span class='publab'><b>In:</b><b:if cond='data:post.labels'><b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'><a expr:href='data:label.url' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a><b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'>, </b:if></b:loop></b:if></span>

  </div>
</div>
```

My blogger template comes with the following Jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".seeds_remove .label_remove").each(function(){
    var e=$(this).text();
    if(e.substr(0,10).match("seeds")) {
      e=e.replace("seeds_","");
      $(this).html('<div class="seeds"><span class="item_seeds">'+e+"</span></div>")}
      $(".seeds").parent(".label_remove").replaceWith(function(){
        return $(this).contents()
      });
      $(".seeds_remove").replaceWith(function(){
        return $(this).contents()
      })
    });
    $(".widget.Label a").each(function(){
      var e=$(this).text();
      if(e.substr(0,10).match("seeds")){
        e=e.replace("seeds_","");
        $(this).html('<span class="tag_remove">'+e+"</span>");
        $(".tag_remove").parent("a").remove()
      }
    });
    $(".widget.Label span").each(function(){
     var e=$(this).text();
     if(e.substr(0,10).match("seeds")){
       e=e.replace("seeds_","");
       $(this).html('<span class="tag_remove">'+e+"</span>");
       $(".tag_remove").parent("span").remove()
     }
    });
    $(".label_remove").remove()
  });
```

Please help!

Comment: Your question is hard to follow, please rephrase or clarify.

Comment: My question is how can I hide the 'seeds_ILO' by adding some additional function in the Jquery. Thank you!